# STAssertEqualObjects compare class

Tags: iphone, ocunit

i trying to cover the test case

a method which return class object.

```
-(ClassName *)returnClass{

return _class;
}

-(void)test_ReturnClass{

id returnObj;

returnObj = [aClassNameObj returnClass];
STAssertNotNil(returnObj, @"return Not NULL Value");
STAssertEqualObjects(returnObj, [isKindOfClass: ClassName],@"");

}
```

I want to compare an show `STAssertEqualObjects` `isKindOfClass:ClassName` is it possible if yes please let me know.

@All 
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking.

1. If you want to check if the returned object's class is `ClassName` or a subclass, you can use something like this:

   ```
   STAssertTrue([returnObj isKindOfClass:[ClassName class]], nil);
   ```
2. If you want to check that it's a `ClassName` **and not a subclass** (this seems permissible in a unit test, but not in normal code), instead use something like this:

   ```
   STAssertTrue([returnObj isMemberOfClass:[ClassName class]], nil);
   ```
3. If you *really* want to use STAssertEqualObjects, you might use something like this (this also checks that the classes are *equal*; it does not allow the instance to be a subclass):

   ```
   STAssertEqualObjects([returnObj class], [ClassName class], nil);
   ```

Personally, I'd stick to option 1. Option 2 is something I've never needed to use in production code, and option 3 is even worse (there are a few legitimate uses of `[foo class]`, but comparing it to another class with `-equals:` isn't really one of them).